# ImageView makes text input lag

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, android-edittext, imageview

I have a system where I make the user pick a image from the device gallery and, after checking if the pic needs to be rotated put it in an ImageView, the problem is that when the image is put in the imageview the Edittext lag and write something 2/3 second after keyboard input

Here's the code that I execute after the user pic:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE&& resultCode == RESULT_OK) //if the pick of an image is successful
    {
        imageuri = data.getData();
        try{
          ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            img.setClickable(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(getApplicationContext(), imageuri, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()); //extract the image and check if it needs to be rotated
            Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }
```

and Here's the functions that check if the image needs to be rotated:

```
public static Bitmap handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(Context context, Uri selectedImage, int w, int h)
        throws IOException {
    int MAX_HEIGHT =h;
    int MAX_WIDTH = w;

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    InputStream imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
    imageStream.close();

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);

    img = rotateImageIfRequired(context, img, selectedImage);
    return img;
}

private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee a final image
        // with both dimensions larger than or equal to the requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;

        // This offers some additional logic in case the image has a strange
        // aspect ratio. For example, a panorama may have a much larger
        // width than height. In these cases the total pixels might still
        // end up being too large to fit comfortably in memory, so we should
        // be more aggressive with sample down the image (=larger inSampleSize).

        final float totalPixels = width * height;

        // Anything more than 2x the requested pixels we'll sample down further
        final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

        while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}

 private static Bitmap rotateImageIfRequired(Context context, Bitmap img, Uri selectedImage) throws IOException {

    InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    ExifInterface ei;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23)
        ei = new ExifInterface(input);
    else
        ei = new ExifInterface(selectedImage.getPath());

    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            return RotateImage(img, 90);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            return RotateImage(img, 180);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            return RotateImage(img, 270);
        default:
            return img;
    }
}

 protected static Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap img, float degree)
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degree);
    Bitmap rotatedImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    img.recycle();
    return rotatedImg;
}
```

I tried Reducing a lot the resolution but to not have lag it would need to set a resolution so low that is basically a big pxel

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to find a work around using [this library](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) which is made especially for large bitmaps, now I have no lag